# How to programmatically generate sub addresses using the root address in hd wallet?

Tags: addresses, private-key, eth-lightwallet, hd-wallets

And without using the private key. I've been digging into the ConsenSys's eth-lightwallet, although it uses a derived private key to generate the address which would expose the root private in danger.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate new addresses with extended public key, but you'll have access to them just with your extended private key. In [bip32 standard](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) there is an explanation of how the process is going. Also you can read [bip44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) for better understanding of process.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet
you can use `fromExtendedKey` method of `'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey'`